# MySql date_sub() function in Hibernate Query Language and find last week date range

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

how can I make the following hql query to retrieve records with timestamp of the last week?

`timestamp` in MySQL `DATETIME` type (eg: 05/07/2012 11:51:34)

```
select * from transaction
where timestamp between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  Can you give some example data & desired output?

Answer (score 2):

HQL is meant to be fairly database vendor-neutral, so you can't really do this directly in HQL.

The two things that you can do are:

1. Calculate the date range in your java code, instead of in the database.
2. Use Hibernate's native query facilities - see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html